# Run GUI program in bash without opening the window

Tags: bash, gui

Is it possible to run a GUI program and tell bash to not show the window? E.g. something like `nogui firefox` that runs Firefox but don't show the GUI window.

Let me explain my situation: I am processing some images with the program [ds9](http://ds9.si.edu/site/Home.html). I have a bash script that opens an image in *.fits* format format with this program, then export it as *.jpeg* and then closes the program. It is working perfectly fine. However, each time I run this script, the GUI window of ds9 opens up, then exports the image and then closes. This is annoying when converting many images because there are windows opening an closing automatically for each image.

Comment: It is up to the GUI app if it supports "headless" mode.  Looks like Firefox does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode

Comment: Yeah, I know that there are apps that support this. Unfortunately I didn't find this option for ds9. Thus I was wondering whether it is possible to tell bash to hide the window.

Comment: That would be up to the developers of ds9 if that is supported or not.  Other than that, maybe look at running it on a server that you ssh to or create a VM to run it.

Answer (score -1):

Coded by yours truly:

> [unwin](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/unwin) [program]

Comment: since your program is a Bash script, it would be nice if you would explain the principles here...

Comment: Hi fellow vegan. Just from yesterday: https://i.imgur.com/dLZ7Lkr.jpg

Comment: The main feature of my food, as in my software, is what's missing.

Comment: haha looks yum :)

Comment: 